# How to Install the latest version of seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn

I want to create a catplot using seaborn package and I know that in order to be able to do that I need the latest version of seaborn(0.9.0). I installed the package for conda using:

```css
 conda install seaborn
```

but it downloaded version 0.8.1.

I therefore installed the version that I want using pip:

```css
 pip3 install seaborn==0.9.0
```

but I keep getting the same error whenever I run my code:
 **AttributeError: module 'seaborn' has no attribute 'catplot'** (attribute that is only available in the latest version).

Can anyone please assist with this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Apparently conda has not yet integrated seaborn 0.9.0 into it's default channel. You may still try to get it through `conda-forge`

```
conda install -c conda-forge seaborn
```

You can also use pip from within the conda environment in use.

```
> activate
(base) > python -mpip install seaborn==0.9.0
```

Current versions of the Anaconda distribution already have `seaborn` installed, so `conda update seaborn` will update the package to the currently available version on the default / available conda channel. All packages can be updated with `conda update --all`.

`conda update --name env seaborn` will update a specific environment, `env` in this case.

`conda install --name env seaborn` will install to a specific environment.

`conda update --name env --all` will update seaborn and all other packages.

It is not recommended to use `pip` to install packages that already exist within the conda environment.

Answer (score 3):

I was having seaborn 0.8.0. This worked for me.

```
sudo -H pip install seaborn==0.9.0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are going for developmental features of seaborn, try installing direct.

```
pip install git+https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn.git#egg=seaborn
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
conda install -c anaconda seaborn
```

Credit: https://anaconda.org/anaconda/seaborn

Answer (score -2):

After you install a new version restart your Kernel and run your script again.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, which is _How to Install the latest version of seaborn_