# Seaborn Lineplot Module Object Has No Attribute 'Lineplot'

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization, seaborn

Using seaborn's documentation code to generate a lineplot returns an AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lineplot'. I have updated seaborn and reimported the module and tried again, no luck. Did lineplot get retired, or is there something else going on?

```
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fmri = sns.load_dataset("fmri")
ax = sns.lineplot(x="timepoint", y="signal", data=fmri)
```

Comment: upgrade seaborn to 0.9

Comment: If you add `print(sns.__version__)` to your code, what does it print? If it's not 0.9.0,  the seaborn update was not successful.

Comment: Updated using "sudo -H pip install seaborn==0.9.0" and it worked, thanks bois

Comment: Follow the ScottBoston and ImportanceOfBeingErnest comments, and then remember reboot the kernel of your notebook :) #beenThere

Answer (score 11):

If you are using conda, you need to install seaborn with the version specified:

```
conda install -c anaconda seaborn=0.9.0
```

Once your seaborn 0.9.0 is installed properly, you should be able to use the lineplot function (at least it works on mine).

That way you don't have to go outside of the conda ecosystem and use seaborn with pip.

Answer (score 4):

Lineplot works with update to seaborn 0.9. conda has not yet integrated seaborn 0.9.0 into it's default channel, which is why the update to 0.9 failed on my first go.

[Couldn't Update Seaborn via Default Channel but found another way to do it through this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51422146/install-the-latest-version-of-seaborn-0-9-0-through-pip)

Answer (score 3):

As other's said before, you need `seaborn` version `0.9.0` (or above will work too, I guess). The `pip`-way of doing this without `conda` is:

```
pip install seaborn==0.9.0
```

My problem was that I had an older version ( `0.8.x`) installed, so simply running `pip install seaborn` doesn't help in that case.

Alternatively, you can directly upgrade to the latest version of `seaborn` like this:

```
pip install -U seaborn
```

Answer (score 1):

Within Jupyter notebook you can run the install without leaving the notebook.

You only have to add the tag "y" to install the package.

```
!conda install -y -c anaconda seaborn=0.9.0
```