# Module seaborn has no attribute lineplot

Tags: machine-learning

I don't know why it's showing this although I installed all packages. I uninstalled and reinstalled python and also did 'pip install seaborn' but it's showing the same problem as mentioned below

[Module seaborn has no attribute lineplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxHsJ.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51846948/seaborn-lineplot-module-object-has-no-attribute-lineplot

Answer (score 1):

Install seaborn version 0.9.0

For conda

```py
conda install -c anaconda seaborn=0.9.0
```

For pip

```py
pip install seaborn==0.9.0
```